# I just set up and used remote log in on my pc and now my mouse is stuttering and beeping when I move or press anything

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, mouse

So basically i remoted in from my laptop and I logged off, but now my mouse stutters and every time i move it or click any buttons on it, it will move but it wont click anything. everytime it moves in that chunky little way, it'll beep and every time I press a button it'll beep too. All programs and thigns are working normally, (i've navigated to this page using only the keyboard tabbing through everything). I'm in the middle of like a 10 hour long encryption of my drive using bitlocker and would like access to my computer without interrupting that process. I've opened video files and they work fine, I opened a game and it was running smoothly. I have no idea what's going on.

edit: I just opened OBS on my second monitor and started recording and my mouse was not moving on the recording but on the screen it was. WTF? Also no sound in the recording. if I restart my computer will I have to start my encryption process again?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried, you can use the command line to view your bitlocker progress and even pause it if you want to reboot your laptop.

```
manage-bde -status C:

manage-bde -pause

manage-bde -resume
```

It sounds to me like your laptop might be overheating so a reboot / break would probably be good.

Comment: it's a desktop. I have a h100i water cooler in it. It's definitely not overheating it just started doing this instantly after my first remote in. Thanks for the pause and resume thing though!

Comment: Ah yea, probably not overheating.